# Can changed file be restored(old_version) → Currently no previous version available

Tags: windows-7, restore, window, windows-7-restore

I had a file on my m/c functions.php until July 10, 2017: the day when the new hard disk was installed, but some how the file got changed and is now of 0KB; there is no previous version available as the hard disk is new. can some how the old version of that file be recovered; the one that was available on the above-mentioned date after which it got altered.

File name is/was `functions.php`

Comment: Since you don't have a backup, only someone who really knows how to recover "lost" information will be able to help. If you have written anything to that drive since that happened, your chances of recovery are very slim.

Comment: I haven't written anything. It just got replaced by some another file. It was downloaded from HostGator server, but as I was using a plugin in my atom editor that uploaded the changed file to the hostgator server aslo. i also do not have backup active there also as it is shared hosting.